# List Row Separators No Longer Showing Up With iOS 17

Tags: list, swiftui, ios17

Does anyone know why in iOS 17 using Xcode 15, list row separators don't show up?

This code was working fine in iOS 16.

I found what is causing the issue, but it appears to be a bug. In order to get the text description and the list to scroll together, I create the first list item as the text description. Then I have a ForEach to display the actual list contents. Used to work perfectly.

If I place the text description outside of the List and only have the ForEach, the row separators and correct colors appear properly. With the text description in the List, it's all the ForEach background color with no separators.

This is an example of how to reproduce:

```
ZStack {
    Color(.blue)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    VStack {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            List {
                Section {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 3) {
                        Text("Header")
                        Text("A small paragraph description")
                    }
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 20, leading: 20, bottom: 28, trailing: 20))
                    .listRowBackground(Color(.pink))
                    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)

                    ForEach(1..<10) { value in
                        Text("\(value)")
                    }
                }
                .listRowInsets(
                    EdgeInsets(
                        top: 0,
                        leading: 0,
                        bottom: 0,
                        trailing: 0
                    )
                )
                .listRowBackground(Color(.green))
                .listRowSeparatorTint(Color(.white))
                .listRowSeparator(.visible)
                .listSectionSeparator(.hidden)
            }
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
.navigationTitle("")
.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
```

Comment: I guess it could be to do with the colors you use "PickerBkg" and "sepLine".
 In my tests, if I use `.listRowBackground(Color.pink)` and
 `.listRowSeparatorTint(Color.green)` the separators show up.

Comment: Nope. No colors or modifiers were used when I stripped it down to a bare list and still no separators. Is your build target iOS 17.0 using XCode 15?

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue with the code provided, even when I use the second code snippet.
 All works well for me in my tests, on latest MacOS 14, Xcode 15, tested on real ios 17 devices (not Previews), and macCatalyst.
 It could be different on older systems.
 
 Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Updated with tested reproducible example and explanation. I too am testing on a real device, not the simulator.

Comment: The new code (`ZStack {...}`) still works well for me in my tests, green list background and white line separator.

Answer (score 0):

It may just be a bug, but the solution was to put everything on the NavigationPath() binding for NavigationStack. If I used programmatic navigation to get to my custom picker view, passing a binding bool, the list was not rendering correctly (hence the question). However, once I put everything on the NavigationPath, it all renders perfectly.